# How to use Teamcity commands (##teamcity[...])?

Tags: continuous-integration, environment-variables, teamcity, tagging

I want to pass some information to another build step. E.g. for build tagging. How do I do that?

I've tried `##teamcity[setParameter name='xxx' value='111']` in my script, but it doesn't seem to do anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, first you need to define custom parameter in `Build configuration -> Parameters`. Then you should set it like in question, but with one nuance: you should `echo` command! And there isn't a word about that in docs :(

In the end, you need to do this: `echo ##teamcity[setParameter name='xxx' value='111']` in your script, and then, in next build step you could use it as usual Teamcity variable: `%xxx%`.

P.S. `xxx` would be initialized only in next build step, so don't use it for anything else but setting value in this build step.